# Android SDK. Get NOTIFICATION_SERVICE to resume, not start new instance

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo, android-notifications

I am really moving forward with my android application. I was able to implement `onDestroy() and onPause()` routines.

I have also managed to get Android's notification service to place my icon with title and body in the notification bar/task menu.

The only problem with this notification service is that if my android app is already running, and has initiated the `onPause()` function that `super.onPause(); moveTaskToBack(true);`, if a users taps the notification, it will bring up a NEW instance of my app.

Once the user interacts with the new instance, the program will crash because the background version is already running, causing conflicts.

Here's my notification code, I need help in making this code look for an already running version of my app:

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificatonManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
CharSequence tickerText = "app name";
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
CharSequence contentTitle = "app title";
CharSequence contentText = "text";
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SuperMicProActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
final int signed = 1;
mNotificatonManager.notify(signed, notification);
```

I was looking at `onResume()` with may be some sort of `bringTaskToFront(this)` option. Does this exist?

Thanks,

Comment: Nevermind.

I simply opened my Manifest file and added `android:launchMode="singleTop"` inside my `<activity` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues, IMHO.

> and has initiated the onPause() function that super.onPause(); moveTaskToBack(true);

That is rather strange behavior. Why are you doing this?

> Once the user interacts with the new instance, the program will crash because the background version is already running, causing conflicts.

Then whatever was being done in the original activity should not be in an activity at all, but in a service. Once you no longer have a foreground activity, the odds of Android terminating your process to free up memory is fairly high and may occur rather quickly, depending on what else is going on. You seem to be depending upon that older activity somehow still doing something. A "background version" of an activity should not be doing anything that would impact any other activity in your process, and an activity not in the foreground should not be responsible for doing anything that the user might miss if the activity goes "poof".

That being said, there are other reasons to avoid having a second copy of your activity, notably navigation -- as it stands, when the user presses BACK from the second copy of the activity, they will see the first copy, and get confused.

> I need help in making this code look for an already running version of my app

No, you "need help in making this code look for an already running version of" your activity. An app is not an activity. An activity is not an app.

Adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to your `Intent` will solve this:

```
  Intent i=new Intent(this, SuperMicProActivity.class);

  i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

  PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
```

This will bring your existing activity to the foreground and, if needed, get rid of other activities in your task.

Comment: Very nice. If you look at my comment below my first question, I added single top to the manifest file. Will adding the new intent code you gave me allow for more redundancy on other devices, or will all android devices follow the single top in the manifest file? Would I use that in `onResume()`?

Comment: @MarcBrown: All devices will follow the manifest file. "Would I use that in onResume()?" -- would you use what in `onResume()`?

Comment: I would use your `new Intent` code in `onResume()` with `@Override`

Comment: @MarcBrown: I sure hope not. Your source code in your question is creating a `Notification`. My recommendation was for you to add some flags to the `Intent` that you are creating for your `Notification`, based upon the source code that is in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I removed `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to make sure the script was working itself, and it did. I re-added `launchMode` to the Manifest and the program continued to run. I tried the `onResume()` and the app would not start. Just what I wanted; back button kills, home moves to back, and the notification link uses the already existing ACTIVITY.

Answer (score 0):

Yes something like that is possible. You need to use flags.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags(int)

You should look into these 2 in particular.

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
[FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)